# Is travelling to Jordan in July just challenging or dangerous in terms of the summer heat?

Tags: weather-and-climate, jordan, summer, deserts

I am planning on travelling to Jordan in July, where temperatures potentially reach into the 40s °C. Travel sites and guides suggest either spring or late fall months, with remarks about the heat during the summer months.

I'll stay for around a week, driving around the country visiting the most important sights and places.

I understand the heat to be a challenging factor, therefore I am taking necessary precautions by wearing long-sleeved linen shirts, pants and head protection and/or a shemagh, as well as bringing along enough water.

Since there are obvious second thoughts when planning a desert trip in Summer, do I have to reconsider, because the heat will make the trip really unpleasant or even dangerous?

Comment: I think this will depend largely on your own heat sensitivity which varies a lot from person to person and what you are used to. I'd be totally fine with it but my partner would be utterly miserable. They can't deal with heat well. If you take proper precautions and pace yourself, it's not dangerous but if you are heat sensitive it might not be fun either. Beware of dehydration!!: my cousin just moved from Southern California to Phoenix and ended up in the hospital with kidney stones because of dehydration. Even someone who is used to "hot" can make this mistake.

Comment: @Hilmar: Thanks for your input! Obviously personal condition is a major contributing factor, you are right. I consider myself in good condition, so I wanted to check if the plan is dangerous even with the necessary preparations.

Comment: @pat3d3r Given that people live there, once you are acclimated then obviously there are no real issues.  In addition, the climate of the SW (Aqaba) is going to be totally different from the NE (Ruwaished).  But you are asking if it will be dangerous for you, and we can't answer that as we don't know you personally.  For me 40c isn't an issue and I've overnight hiked in temps like that.

Comment: @PeterM: Thanks, your last sentence is something I was looking for.